# Figure with multiple traces in subplots

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I'm trying to create a plot containing 3 subplots, each subplot containing a number of lines plus 2 threshold lines. So far I'm able to create the subplots and plot a couple of lines, but when I want to add more than 2 lines, it won't display them.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
    # Make many subplots
    for p_i in range(poses_values_array.shape[1]-6): 
        if p_i%3 == 0:
            main_fig = subplots.make_subplots(rows=3, cols=1, subplot_titles=("lLeg","rLeg","Hip"))
        fig = go.Figure()                    
        
        # Treshold lines
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x= list(range(poses_values_array.shape[2])), 
                                 y= [pose_max[p_i]] * poses_values_array.shape[2], 
                                 name=f'Max Pose {pose_motion[p_i%3]} {pose_names[int(p_i/3)]} Threshold'))  

        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x= list(range(poses_values_array.shape[2])), 
                                 y= [pose_min[p_i]] * poses_values_array.shape[2], 
                                 name=f'Min Pose {pose_motion[p_i%3]} {pose_names[int(p_i/3)]} Threshold'))     
        
        # Data                      
        for t_i in range(poses_values_array.shape[0]):               
            fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=list(range(len(poses_values_array[t_i, p_i, :]))), 
                                     y=poses_values_array[t_i, p_i, :], 
                                     name=f'Target {t_i+1} - Pose {pose_motion[p_i%3]} {pose_names[int(p_i/3)]}'))
        
        fig.update_layout(title=f'Pose {p_i}',
                        xaxis_title='Dataset',
                        yaxis_title='Pose Value')
        fig.update_yaxes(autorange=False, zeroline=True, zerolinewidth=2, zerolinecolor='LightPink')
        
        # Update the subplots
        for i in range (poses_values_array.shape[0]):
            main_fig.append_trace(fig.data[i], row=(p_i%3)+1, col=1)
            main_fig.update_layout(title=f'Aggregated {pose_names[int(p_i/3)]} Pose {p_i}-{p_i+3}')
        # Update subplots individual subtitles
        main_fig.layout.annotations[p_i%3].update(text=f"{pose_names[int(p_i/3)]} {pose_motion[p_i%3]} Pose")
```

I also tried placing the `Threshold` lines after the for loop that plots `Data`, resulting in my current 2 lines (will have more actually) of data showing up but not the treshold lines.

I tried too using `fig.add_hline()` with the same result.

This is what results from the code. Ideally I would like to see the `t_i` lines of data in between the thresholds lines:
[image]

Hope I can get a hint of what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Oh, wow, soon after posting this question, giving another read to my code, I found the error.

I was not taking into account the threshold lines as part of `fig.data`, so I was only looping through the first 2 traces that were added to it on the `# Update subplots` line. I just had to switch `for i in range (poses_values_array.shape[0])` to `for i in range (poses_values_array.shape[0]+2)`.